# Почему не отображаются маркеры на яндекс карте? версия 3, ymaps3

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Полный код, координаты выводятся корректно в консоли, на 2 версии маркеры показываются

```
ymaps3.ready.then(init);

// Инициализация и уничтожение карты при нажатии на кнопку.
function init () {
    let myMap;

    $('#toggle').bind({
        click: function () {
            if (!myMap) {
                const {YMap, YMapDefaultSchemeLayer, YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer, YMapMarker} = ymaps3;
                myMap = new YMap(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    location:{
                        zoom: 9,
                        center: [55.010251, 82.958437], // Новосибирск
                        }
                    
                } /* {
                    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
                } */);

                const layer = new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer();
                const layer2 = new YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer();
                myMap.addChild(layer);
                myMap.addChild(layer2);
                /* console.log(pointArr); */

                const content = document.createElement('section');
                for (let i = 0; i < pointArr.length; i++) {
                    let point = pointArr[i];
                    /* myMap.setLocation({center:[point.latitude, point.longitude], zoom: 5}); */
                    let marker = new YMapMarker({coordinates: [point.latitude, point.longitude], draggable: true}, content);
                    myMap.addChild(marker);
                    console.log([point.latitude, point.longitude]);
                    
                    
                }
                
                $("#toggle").attr('value', 'Скрыть карту');
            }
            else {
                myMap.destroy();// Деструктор карты
                myMap = null;
                $("#toggle").attr('value', 'Показать карту снова');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалось подключить маркеры.

Импортировал пакет:

```
const {YMapDefaultMarker} = await ymaps3.import('@yandex/ymaps3-markers@0.0.1');
// Импортируем пакет, чтобы добавить маркер по умолчанию
```

вместо YMapMarker использовал:

```
let marker = new YMapDefaultMarker(
    {coordinates: [point.longitude, point.latitude], draggable: false});
```

Answer (score 1):

В **API 3.0** Яндекс координаты следует прописывать в фиксированном порядке **(longitude, latitude)**. Как в версии 2.1 при подключении API порядок изменить нельзя.

В вашем примере координаты Новосибирска и точек перепутаны местами. Попробуйте указать их с правильным порядком **LngLat**.

Comment: да, координаты были перепутаны, но дело было не в этом, ниже предоставил ответ